# Matrix of the Heights of the the connected component of each pixel in Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a B=700x800 binary image in matlab.What I want to do is that I need a  matrix A of same size as B but instead of storing just pixels I want it to contain the height corresponding to connected component that pixel belongs to in binary Image.

How would I do that?

**Referencs**

Page 5 about the formation of matrix A
[Extraction and Recognition of Artificial
Text in Multimedia Documents](http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/papers/tr-rfv-2002-01.pdf)

Comment: You can use `bwlabel` to label connected components in 2-D binary image, and then for each region, compute its height along the Y-axis. These numbers will populate your A matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use region props and with the bounding box proprieties and pixelIdList
2. For each connected component give all the pixels the height value according to the bounding box

The code:

```
row = 100;
col = 100;
% Create a sample binary image
a = zeros(row,col);
a(20:30,40:60) = 1;
a(1:10,80:90) = 1;

% Finds bounding box of each component
regions = regionprops(im2bw(a),'BoundingBox','PixelIdxList');

% Go over each region and assigne is height
heightImage = zeros(row,col);
for i=1:1:length(regions)

    % Change the pixels of the component to have the hight of the its
    % bounding box

    regionPixels = regions(i).PixelIdxList;
    regionHegiht = regions(i).BoundingBox(4);

    heightImage(regionPixels) = regionHegiht;

end


imshow(heightImage)
```